# What if I don't want to await 2 methods but wait for both to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 async methods like below. What if I want both to run simultaneously but wait for both to finish then proceed.

```
exports.get = async id => {
    const part1 = await context.get(id);
    const part2 = await context.get2(id);
    //run both asynchronously, but wait until both are finished
};
```

Comment: Have you looked up `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of `Promise.all`

```
exports.get = async id => {
    const [part1, part2] = await Promise.all([context.get(id), context.get2(id)]);
};
```